# How to send sms on switching off the phone in android?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadCast receiver class which listens on Switching off the phone, Now  i wanted to send Sms when the phone is Switching off. Is it possible or not?

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061321/how-can-i-send-an-sms-from-a-broadcastreceiver-and-check-its-status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out this example of smsmanager.

Visit http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

this is simplest example of SMSMANAGER.....

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/03/send-sms-using-androidtelephonysmsmanag.html

[How can I send an SMS from a BroadcastReceiver and check its status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061321/how-can-i-send-an-sms-from-a-broadcastreceiver-and-check-its-status)

Comment: yes I have checked it already. This example shows how to implement on activity class. I wanted it on BroadCast receiving & getting problem over specifying Pending intent . What shall i specify here on pending intent . Ex -- PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,SMSMesseagingActivity.class), 0);

Comment: Ok silent_killer Thanks !! i will  go thorough it!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. Look up `SmsManager` and you'll see an API you can use.

Comment: ok I know SmsManager but how can i implement it into Broadcast receiver class?

Comment: Once you see the api, it should be pretty obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Take a multimedia phone ,It is must because these types of phones will never off with this SMS
2) Then Go to Menu >>> Message >>> Write new message
3) Type 51 commas(for some of the phones or phone OS versions you need to use 79 commas instead of 51) [ ' ] like below(These are inverted commas)