# how can i use late posting in android

Tags: android, facebook, wifi

i have develop an Facebook application in android.in that i have to post a message in my Facebook wall. my doubt is, if my application loaded in my mobile,i want to post my message in my wall only if wife/network connection is ON otherwise it will run on back round until network is connected once network is connect my message post on Facebook wall is it possible.

Comment: What have you tried, and what do you think you need to do? Stop asking such vague questions and atleast have an idea of what you want to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891212/how-to-send-sms-on-switching-off-the-phone-in-android/8891237#8891237 like this i have to send text on facebook wall is it possible or not?

Comment: Of course it would be possible, you'd just have to figure out where the messaging is coming from, where that message should go, and how it can update.

Answer (score 3):

From the sounds of it you want to defer network communications until you have a wifi connection, in this case for Facebook wall posts.

I would first part of the problem is to handle messages when they are initially posted.  You could use a service for this that will on receipt of a message will, check the wifi status and either post is available, or store this message in a queue if its not.

The second part is to register a [BroadcastReciever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that will start the above service on the following intents.

```
android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED
android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE
```

Once it receives one of these intents, it can check the status of the message queue, check the status of wifi, and if its connected post the messages.

Comment: thanks for u r response i edited my question